# How to make duplicate of whole HDD

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 production server with 500 GB (nearly 15 GB used) HDD. I want to duplicate whole HDD including it's partitions structure, data to another HDD with 400 GB size so that changing HDD will not affect working system.

Which tool is the best solution for this task?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208/whats-the-best-linux-backup-solution) thread.

For more information also take a look at these links:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backup_Programs
- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-outstanding-linux-backup-utilities/

Google is always your good friend :)

Comment: This is not a "simple" case of just using any backup tool, as the target partition will be smaller.

Comment: @slhck yeah I know. but that is a problem when you want use `dd` like to clone the whole HDD. but when using `tar` like solution they can handle the size change. Most backup solution use the latter solution. the first one is the last option and worst.